# Redim Preserve fires 'Out of Range' error

Tags: excel, vba, multidimensional-array

I want to generate a 2-D array, with 2 fixed Columns and dynamic rows. 
The result should be (for example):

```
(row number) , (row group level)
     3       ,         2
     4       ,         2
     6       ,         3
     7       ,         3
     8       ,         3
```

So far I have this code below, which seems to work for the first entry of the array but as soon as I redim the array (second time), error 9 *'Subscript Out of Range'* shows up:

```
Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Sheet1.UsedRange
Dim rws() As String
Dim n As Integer, r As Integer, FirstRow As Integer, LastRow As Integer, g As Integer
Dim groupLevel() As Long, i As Long

i = 1: ReDim Preserve groupLevel(1 To 1, 1 To 2)

'get rows to look in for grouped rows
rws = Split(Replace(rng.AddressLocal, ":", ""), "$")
FirstRow = rws(2)
LastRow = rws(4)

With rng.Rows
     For r = FirstRow To LastRow
            For g = 2 To 8
                If .Rows(r).OutlineLevel = g Then
                    groupLevel(i, 1) = r
                    groupLevel(i, 2) = .Rows(r).OutlineLevel
                    i = i + 1
                    ReDim Preserve groupLevel(1 To i, 1 To 2)     '<<<<<<<<<<<<<< error 9
                End If
            Next
     Next r
End With
```

I don't know how to fix this. What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: You can `Redim Preserve` only 1-dimensional array. Multi-dimensional may be only redimmed without preserving data.

Comment: Thanks! So basically, I cannot achieve what I want here. right? 'cause I need to add rows up as I go. Is using a 1-dimensional array that holds a custom type that has row num and group level as properties, a good alternative?

Comment: You can redim preserve multi dimensional arrays, but ONLY the last dimension.

Comment: @Guyglk You can get your dimensions first, then redim your array and then fill it

Comment: @Guyglk You can also use an array of arrays. A 1-dimensional array which have such many arrays as row elements you need. Or nested dictionaries. Than you don't need redim preserve. But this requires a more sophisticated logic to fill.

Comment: Flip your array so you are filling it `groupLevel(1 to 2, 1 to i)` then transpose.  If the array is relatively small you can use `Application.Transpose` or just iterate through the array and fill another array that is transposed.

Comment: Posted a workaround using `Application.Index()` in addition to Scott's valid comment above :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Workaround via `Application.Index()**

Additional to Scott Craner's valid comment to apply `Application.Transpose()` to an array with changed row/column dimensions, I demonstrate an approach using `Application.Index()`.

```
Sub test()
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Sheet1.UsedRange
    Dim rws() As String
    Dim n As Integer, r As Integer, FirstRow As Integer, LastRow As Integer, g As Integer
    Dim groupLevel() As Variant                                     ' <<<< [0] declare as Variant

    Dim i As Long
    i = 1
    groupLevel = rng                                                ' <<<< [1] assign data to 1-based 2-dim array

    'get rows to look in for grouped rows
    rws = Split(Replace(rng.AddressLocal, ":", ""), "$")
    FirstRow = rws(2)
    LastRow = rws(4)
    With rng.Rows
         For r = FirstRow To LastRow
                For g = 2 To 8
                    If .Rows(r).OutlineLevel = g Then
                        groupLevel(i, 1) = r
                        groupLevel(i, 2) = .Rows(r).OutlineLevel
                        i = i + 1
    ''                    ReDim Preserve groupLevel(1 To i, 1 To 2)  ' [2] delete line <<<<<<<<<<<<<< error 9
                    Else
                        If r = 3 Then
                            groupLevel(i, 1) = r
                            groupLevel(i, 2) = g
                        i = i + 1
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
         Next r
    End With
    '[3] provide for single result or no results
    If i < 2 Then i = 2
    '===================================================
    '[4] use Application.Index for pseudo ReDim Preserve
    '---------------------------------------------------
    groupLevel = Application.Index(groupLevel, Evaluate("row(1:" & i & ")"), Array(1, 2))

'write array to any target
'Sheet2.Range("A2").Resize(UBound(groupLevel), UBound(groupLevel, 2)) = groupLevel

End Sub
```

**Further idea**

It's even possible to assign an array with column/row inversion to a listbox'es `.List` property created on the fly by `CreateObject("Forms.ListBox.1")`, remove rows and regain the result via the `.Column` property.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you ALL so much for your input! much appreciated! I've decided to go with Vitaliy Prushak's suggestion and got my array dimensions first, then ReDim'ed once which saves alot of headache...

```
Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Sheet1.UsedRange
Dim rws() As String
Dim r As Integer, FirstRow As Integer, LastRow As Integer, g As Integer
Dim groupLevel(), RowsCount As Long, i As Long

'get rows to look in for grouped rows
rws = Split(Replace(rng.AddressLocal, ":", ""), "$")
FirstRow = rws(2)
LastRow = rws(4)

'get dimentions for array first ----------------------------------
With rng.Rows
For r = FirstRow To LastRow
    If .Rows(r).OutlineLevel > 1 Then RowsCount = RowsCount + 1
    Next r '------------------------------------------------------

    'set array----------------------------------------------------
    ReDim groupLevel(1 To RowsCount, 1 To 2)
    '-------------------------------------------------------------

    'populate array with rows using a group-----------------------
    i = 1
    For r = FirstRow To LastRow
           For g = 2 To 8
               If .Rows(r).OutlineLevel = g Then
                   groupLevel(i, 1) = r
                   groupLevel(i, 2) = .Rows(r).OutlineLevel
                   i = i + 1
               End If
           Next
    Next r'-------------------------------------------------------

End With

'for debug
For r = 1 To UBound(groupLevel, 1)
        Debug.Print "Row " & groupLevel(r, 1) & vbTab & " GroupLevel [" & groupLevel(r, 2) & "]"
Next r
Debug.Print " ************ end *************"
```

One thing that still bothers me though is having to use the same `For ... Next` twice, once to only check for outline level greater than 1 in order to determine array size, and a second time to actually populate the array. There isn't a way around that, is there? I'm asking because the number of rows can vary greatly (in some cases a dozen, in other cases hundreds or thousands..).

Wouldn't that slow down when looping through large ranges? I would also need to apply much of the same thing to check for grouped columns as well..

Thanks!